# Query that will return year over year growth in touchpoints by channel for each complete week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to calculate year over year growth in touchpoints by location for each complete week to date in 2020, here's my sample data, where each record is touchpoint:

```
login_id    location      time

1001        India       1/1/2020 6:52
1010        USA         1/2/2020 14:27
1021        India       2/2/2020 4:55
1021        India       2/1/2020 10:17
```

I'm not able to understand what year over year growth for each complete week means, do I need to calculate growth week over week, or how can I do that, any help will be highly appreciated. I tried year over year growth by following query, but I'm not getting desired output:

```
select location, YEAR(time), COUNT(*)
from table
group by location, YEAR(time)
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
select location, date_trunc('year', time),
       COUNT(*) as cnt,
       lag(count(*)) over (partition by location order by date_trunc('year', time)) as prev_cnt
from table
group by location, date_trunc('year', time);
```

This puts the previous value in the same row -- assuming that there is data for all years.  You can then do whatever calculations you like.